# RxJava: run observable on a different thread and block

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I want to run an observable and wait for it to finish, blocking. The reason why is that I'm already on a background thread and I need to get the result in order to return success or failure.

Testing in a sample app, I do:

```
Completable.fromRunnable(() -> System.out.println(String.format("[%s] observable", Thread.currentThread().getName())))
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.single())
    .doOnComplete(() -> System.out.println(String.format("[%s] complete", Thread.currentThread().getName())))
    .blockingAwait();
  System.out.println(String.format("[%s] main", Thread.currentThread().getName()));
```

Which prints (as I expected):

```
[RxSingleScheduler-1] observable
[RxSingleScheduler-1] complete
[main] main
```

However, in my Android app, I am in the context of the sync adapter thread (a background thread), and I do the same (?):

```
syncApps.getObservable(SyncApps.DOWNLOAD)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.single())
    .doOnComplete(() -> { ... })
    .doOnError(t -> { ... }
    .blockingAwait();
```

When I log the thread from the observable returned from `syncApps.getObservable()`, I'm still on the same thread from which I initiated the call:

```
03-13 09:55:33.674 22201 25389 I SyncApps: getObservable(SyncApps.java:60): [SyncAdapterThread-2] Started...
...
03-13 09:55:33.683 22201 25389 I SyncApps: getObservable(SyncApps.java:81): [SyncAdapterThread-2] Finished
```

Why am I not running on `Schedulers.single()`? I can't see what would be different.

Comment: What does that `getObservable()` actually do?

Comment: Mainly it goes to the network. There are no other subscribe/observeOn calls down the line, if that's what you are asking.

Comment: Yes and how you're wiring up the Observable (and the log print) there?

Comment: I'm just printing `Thread.currentThread().getName()`.

Comment: Using `fromRunnable()` or something like it?

Comment: It would help to see body of getObservable. Is it deferred or not (in other words is it hot or cold).

Comment: `GET("/XXX")
  Observable<...> getApps(...)`. There's no `defer`.

Comment: Where/when are you actually logging the thread name?

Comment: My guess is that you already use `subscribeOn` somewhere in `syncApps.getObservable(SyncApps.DOWNLOAD)`. But  subscribeOn works only once, so this second one is not applied. You can just change `subscribeOn(Schedulers.single())` to `observeOn(Schedulers.single())`, it will fix your issue